# Configuración de SECRET_KEY no debe estar vacía

Tags: python, django

Estoy creando un proyecto en Django con una app llamada Blog, configuro el archivo `settings.py` pero estoy teniendo problemas con la `SECRET_KEY`, no sé por qué me sale un error de que no puedo contener esta llave vacia. Mi configuración es:

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME':         'blog',
    'USER':         'xxxx',
    'PASSWORD':     'xxxx',
    'HOSTNAME':      '',
    'PORT':          '',
  }
}


SECRET_KEY = '18x&q4kb9oa!qz-7wg(nk#0%w-=49$ylj1gtn1n6^e0pe@@8ge'
```

Toda la configuración resulta estar bien, contengo la `SECRET_KEY`, pero al momento de aplicar las migraciones para la configuración inicial de Django, me sale este error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 190, in fetch_command
klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 40, in load_command_class
module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 19, in <module>
from django.db.migrations.autodetector import MigrationAutodetector
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 13, in <module>
from django.db.migrations.questioner import MigrationQuestioner
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/questioner.py", line 12, in <module>
from .loader import MIGRATIONS_MODULE_NAME
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 10, in <module>
from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 9, in <module>
class MigrationRecorder(object):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 23, in MigrationRecorder
class Migration(models.Model):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 24, in Migration
app = models.CharField(max_length=255)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1081, in __init__
super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 161, in __init__
self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 113, in __init__
raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must    not be empty.
```

Estuve averiguando alguna solución y resulta que en algunos blogs hablan sobre como si modificaste el nombre del proyecto debes de configurar el `manage.py` como sigue:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite_project.settings")
```

Pero la configuración está bien hecha, no sé realmente por qué obtengo este error.

Comment: Si usas el shell de Django: `python manage.py shell`, luego importas tus configuraciones con `from django.conf import settings` y finalmente imprimes con `print settings.SECRET_KEY`, ¿qué te sale?

Comment: Ahora que la has hecho pública, sería conveniente que cambiaras tu `SECRET_KEY`

Comment: Me ha pasado, de echo me pasó cuando migré un proyecto de django 1.9 a 1.10, lo cambié en el manage.py pero en el wsgi.py también tienes que cambiarlo

Answer (score 1):

Si estas configurando tu `SECRET_KEY` correctamente y obtienes el mensaje :

> ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must    not be empty.

Debería ser suficiente como comentas con agregar en tu `manage.py` :

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "projecto.settings.local")
```

Te comento en mi caso tenia el mismo mensaje de error, pero era causado por definir un engine o nombre de base de datos incorrecto:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME':   'blog',
    }
}
```

asegura que estos datos sean correctos.

Answer (score 1):

Buscando en internet halle una solución: (Yo trabajo en Windows)

**1) En la línea de comandos usa:**

> ..> SET SECRET_KEY=''

**2) y en el archivo settings.py declaré la variable:**

> SECRET_KEY= ''

**Puedes revisar la solución en:**
https://github.com/mirumee/saleor/issues/517

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, yo encontré un `snippet` que me genera una llave en un archivo `.txt` cada vez que no hay una llave, y la carga si el archivo existe. Esta configuración puede solucionar tu problema:

```
# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
try:
    SECRET_KEY
except NameError:
    SECRET_FILE = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'quotation', 'secret.txt')
    try:
        SECRET_KEY = open(SECRET_FILE).read().strip()
    except IOError:
        try:
            import random

            SECRET_KEY = ''.join(
                [random.SystemRandom().choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*(-_=+)') for i in range(50)]
            )
            secret = open(SECRET_FILE, 'w')
            secret.write(SECRET_KEY)
            secret.close()
        except IOError:
            Exception('Please create a %s file with random characters \
            to generate your secret key!' % SECRET_FILE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que cambiarlo en el manage.py y también en el wsgi.py, estos tienes que apuntar a tu "production.py" o si sólo estas haciendo pruebas a tu settings.py